# SSH and SCP not working

Tags: ssh, scp

I know that this is not really a server error, but I have been having troubles connecting to my servers via SSH.

To be perfectly clear, I have verified that the servers' SSH server works properly. I've done this by trying to ssh from one server to another via cloud troubleshooting console. I have absolutely no doubt that these servers can accept an SSH connection request and handle it properly. I also dug around the `/var/log/auth.log` file, didn't find my IP even getting to the server. I can ping it, but I cannot access it with SSH or SCP.

After I execute `ssh -vvvvv root@my.domain.com` (replace my.domain.com with my actual domain or the IP address to which the A record/domain is pointing the DNS request to), I get the following output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/custom.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/custom.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/cythero/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/cythero/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "my.domain.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup my.domain.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to my.domain.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
```

It hangs on this for a while, then I get:

```
ssh: connect to host my.domain.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Currently, my `ssh_config` has everything set at default. I tried playing around with the following rules:

```
ForwardX11 yes / no
StrictHostKeyChecking ask (I also deleted old key from known hosts)
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Nothing worked. I am running Manjaro Arch Linux with Gnome 45.12 DE, IDK how much that makes a difference but this has started happening since I did system update.

Comment: You have a firewall that's blocking port 22 somewhere in your path. That's all we can tell, really.

Comment: I disabled the firewall on my machine and I tried changing networks just in case some NAT rules are not forwarding traffic properly, but no luck. Regarding SSHD, I just ran `systemctl status sshd` it shows that it is active and that some bot just tried to access my system (I have firewall disabled on the server temporary)

Comment: When you get connection timeout, *something* along the way is dropping traffic, or the remote computer is not listening on that port. There's no other explanations for timeout.

Comment: The SSH server is running on port 22 perfectly I have no doubt. I am positive that the error happens on my end. I went up and down all my network and ssh configurations, couldn't find anything outside the norm.

Comment: What is confusing me is that I can SSH from another machine but not fro the current. I really don't get it. I thought it is a network issue, I changed to another network (mobile hotspot), then I thought maybe the firewall is at fault, I disabled firewall, then I started digging around conf and log files, nothing noteworthy except connection timed out. I don't understand really. Also, this doesn't happen for all servers. I.e. I can SSH into XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA but not to XXX.YYY.AAA.ZZZ using IP address OR associated domain name / cname / A record etc.

Comment: what does sshd -T say?

Comment: @Turdie I think that the provider is at fault in my case. I just tried from another IS provider and it worked like a charm. I honestly don't know why this happens, I can only assume that their reaction to some sort of DDoS attacks is to just drop or halt all connection requests lol.